# Deny maintenance period configured while CloudSQL instance is already scheduled for routine maintenance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I just specified a "Deny maintenance period" from 1.12.2020 and 31.01.2021

Now I saw that there is already a Maintenance scheduled by Google for my CloudSQL-Instance for Wednesday, 09/12/2020 at 12:00 pm. This information is still displayed also after I configured the "Deny maintenance period".

**Summary**

- On the one hand Google tells me that "instance is scheduled for routine maintenance on Wednesday, 09/12/2020 at 12:00 pm"
- On the other hand I have a maintenance deny period set that includes the schedule for routine maintenance

**My question is now:** Will the maintenance take place on the Wednesday, 09/12/2020 at 12:00 pm with the current configuration or not ?

**Information about my configuration**

Type: MySQL-2nd-Gen

A call to `gcloud sql instances describe <instance-name-omitted>`

```
...
  denyMaintenancePeriods:
  - endDate: 0-1-31
    startDate: 0-12-1
    time: 00:00:00
...
```

Whereas CloudSQL-Overview displays

```
Upcoming
This instance is scheduled for routine maintenance on Wednesday, 09/12/2020 at 12:00 pm (UTC+1). 
Deny maintenance period
You can specify times when maintenance shouldn't occur using gcloud. Learn more
```

This makes me think "Why isn't the configured Deny maintenance period shown in the overview ?"

**What did I find in Googles documentation**

[Documentation on Deny maintenance period](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/maintenance#deny) says

```
The deny maintenance period takes precedence over any scheduled maintenance window.
If there is a conflict between the timing of a maintenance window and the deny maintenance period,
the deny maintenance period overrides the maintenance window.
```

Documentation on [How do I reschedule maintenance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/maintenance) says

```
You can reschedule maintenance to a time that falls within a deny maintenance period,
or even outside the maintenance window, as long as the time falls within the one week 
rescheduling limitation.
```

Comment: How did you configure notifications for `cloudsql` maintenance ?

Comment: @shubham There is a link called "Edit notification preferences" inside the box "Maintenance" on the overview-page of the cloudsql-instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is a bit ambigous on that matter in the links you shared but the most important part is:

> The deny maintenance period takes precedence over any scheduled maintenance window. If there is a conflict between the timing of a maintenance window and the deny maintenance period, the deny maintenance period overrides the maintenance window.

So if you have that maintenance window schedule for `Wednesday, 09/12/2020 at 12:00 pm` and that is a deny maintenance period, it **will not go through maintenance**, which makes sense from a design perspective.

I believe that the reason why Cloud SQL allows you to reschedule a maintenance window to a deny maintenance period is simply in order to make that maintenance window "Inactive".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rafael.

It is just really hard to get a reliable information about what will happen with quite some (unclear ?) information on the CloudSQL-Overview-UI as well.
But I would need this to know if we have to prepare our services for a CloudSQL-Maintenance or not.

E.g. There is a section in the Maintenance-Block about the deny maintenance period but my configured period is not mentioned there. The maintenance window schedule on the other hand is visible everywhere in the CloudSQL-UI.

Comment: Happy to help Christian, if you think that the documentation can be improved and made clearer, which I agree for this particular case, you could open a report with Google Cloud so that they can do so. You can do it by following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0), if you are interested in that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that option - there already was an issue - i added my comments to that - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174580715